# 502 Bad Gateway Error while running the informationProtection API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Getting below error while running labels available to the organization after providing the required permission
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/informationProtection/policy/labels

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "502 Bad Gateway",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-24T07:12:06",
            "request-id": "3fa2b70d-79fd-4ade-b16d-1250be2771a1",
            "client-request-id": "02b1ac97-21c6-75c4-0cbb-403ab53a1108"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Graph Explorer]

Comment: HTTP 502 tells that the API call service is unavailable at the time, when you tried calling. I would suggest you to test the same after sometime to see if it works. If you still see the issue, you can report the issue back here. Also i see that its under beta endpoint, which is not meant for production environments.

Comment: Moving this answer. Consider upvoting it. So it can be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 502 tells that the API call service is unavailable at the time, when you tried calling. I would suggest you to test the same after sometime to see if it works. If you still see the issue, you can report the issue back here. Also i see that its under beta endpoint, which is not meant for production environments